# Geocoder returning empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I am creating a Rails application where I need to find the latitutes and longitutes of places using google maps service. I am using the geocoder gem for this purpose. Seems at times (i.e. for some geographical locations) the `geocoder.search` function returns an empty array. For example, when I type in `Geocoder.search("Janapriya Nile Valley, Hyderabad, Telangana, India")` it works perfect, but when on another instance I write `Geocoder.search("Amazon Development Center, Gachibowli, Hyderabad, Telangana, India")` in my command window, it returns an empty array. I checked this location on google maps and it displays this location perfectly. Has anyone encountered this problem before? What could be the solution?

Comment: I tried to use the Google Maps documentation on Geocoding and this too returns a blank array when I make a query: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Amazon+Development+Center,+Gachibowli,+Hyderabad,+Telangana,+India&key=some_key

Comment: Are you using Ruby geocoding solution? maybe you can fill here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues to see if there is update

Comment: Yes bjiang...I am using the Ruby geocoding solution.

Comment: So you can fill an issue there, may get help quickly